# Who wrote 'Anjaneya Sahasranam'?

Tags: hanuman, stotra

An year ago or so, I found a video titled something like **Hanuman/Anjaneya Sahasranamam**. I am now unable to find it.

Upon Google search, I found text like this which I recall from that video:

हनूमान् श्रीप्रदो वायुपुत्रो रुद्रो नयोऽजरः ।
अमृत्युर्वीरवीरश्च ग्रामवासो जनाश्रयः ॥ १॥

धनदो निर्गुणाकारो वीरो निधिपतिर्मुनिः ।
पिङ्गाक्षो वरदो वाग्मी सीताशोकविनाशनः ॥ २॥

Full text is [here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_hanumaana/anjaneya1000.html).

In spite of quite some searching, I couldn't find the composer of this stotra. I read on an obscure website that the stotra was a result of Ram praising Hanuman, but seemed to be shaky claim.

Any idea about this stotra's origins?

Answer (score 3):

The Anjaneya Sahasranama stotra that is found here: https://stotram.co.in/wp-content/uploads/pdfs/8017/anjaneya-sahasranama-stotram_sanskrit_PDF_file3231.pdf shows that it was Valmiki Rishi who is revealing the stotra to some unnanmed Rishis.

The Viniyogah portion reveals that Ramachandra is the Rishi of the stotra.

> Asya sri hanumata sahasranama stotra maha mantrasya **Sri Ramachandra
> rishih**, Hanuman devata, anushtup chandah, hraam hrim hrum hrum
> bijam, Sri riti Shaktihi ......
>
> [image]

If a Stotra was composed by some Rishi etc. that information is supposed to be found at the end of the Stotra. In this case we only know who has revealed it (Valmiki Rishi) and we also know who is the Rishi of the Stotra (Ramachandra).

Some might say that Rishi of a Stotra/Mantra is the one who composed it but that's not right. Rishi is the one to whom that Mantra or Stotra was revealed for the first time.